# Trying to change color of text

Tags: css

I am trying to change the color of the original sales price of an item on my website to Red.

I have tried changing the CSS as follows:

```
.saso-was-price {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

However, the text of the original price remains black.

Could someone tell me whether there is an error in the code above or if I would have to change the color in another place?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should be declaring `color` rules to change font colour, **e.g:** `color: #ff0000;`

Comment: Did you assume that just setting `text-decoration-color` will change the text color?

Comment: `color: #FF0000`

Comment: It work's normally check this http://jsfiddle.net/owwyg35b/

Comment: If I use the following, the color of the text remains black:     .saso-was-price {
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-decoration-color: #FF0000;
        font-size: 14px;
        opacity: 0.8;
        }

Comment: @Maximus000 just add color:#FF0000; and it will work

Comment: @Mario. Thank you but I tried as you say and it does not seem to work..

Comment: Is that style "crossed out" when you inspect the element in question? Sounds like it is being over-qualified, you can rule this out by using the `!important` declaration - if that works you know it's a specificity issue, and you will most likely need to use more *selectors* in your rule to add specificity.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:**

```
.saso-was-price {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```